# Parsing individual letters from string in JAVA

Tags: java, parsing, char

I've almost got it except when I run the program it parses all but the first letter of the string Hello World: "e l l o  w o r l d." Heres my code; what am I missing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class encodeTesting {

      public static void main(String []Args){
          //Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
          String x = "Hello World "; //TEST STRING
          //System.out.println(x.length()); //Console log test
          char[] y = new char[x.length()]; // Array Y

          //Defining Variables:
          int i;
          int z = 0;
          int a = 1;

          while(a<x.length()){ //should repeat as many times as needed to parse String X
              //Parse Algorithm follows:
              y[z] = x.charAt(x.length() - a);
              System.out.println(y[z]);
              z = z + 1;
              a = a + 1;
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] Args) {
        String x = "Hello World ";
        char[] y = new char[x.length()];
        int i;
        int z = 0;
        int a = 1;
        while (a <= x.length()) {
            y[z] = x.charAt(x.length() - a);
            System.out.println(y[z]);
            z = z + 1;
            a = a + 1;
        }
    }
```

You need to use:
`while (a <=x.length())`
So that when `x.charAt(x.length() - a);` evaluates at `x.charAt(0);` getting the first character of the string.

Comment: That will still start at the first char, and not the zero char

Answer (score 0):

You could make this simple and do a basic `for` loop.

```
public static void main(String[] Args){
    String x = "Hello World ";
    int length = x.length();

    char[] y = new char[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        y[i] = x.charAt(length - i - 1);
        System.out.println(y[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something for each character in your string, this is the way to do it:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    String test = "Hello world";
    for(char c: test.toCharArray()) {
        //do your operations here
        System.out.print(c);
    }   
}

//Output: Hello World
```

Read the for-loop as "for each character in test"

By the looks of it you just want to convert your string to a character array, in which case just use this:

```
String myStringVariable = "abc";
char[] stringAsArray = myStringVariable.toCharArray();
```

Or you can even do it like this:

```
char[] stringAsArray = "Hello world".toCharArray();
```